# Adding Google Account in iOS 10

Tags: ios, google-sync

I have upgraded my iPhone to iOS 10. I am not able to add my Google account to sync my Contacts, Mail etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: Add to your question what you've already done to solve the problem.  That way we don't research and add answers for steps that you've already taken.

Comment: you need to elaborate on the subject, otherwise we would not be managed to help you. You have to provide the details, what message are you getting on the screen, after what step, what actions you taken, was the sync with Google working before, etc. Please, *edit* your asnwer correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

To add Google Account, go to `Settings app → Mail → Accounts → Add Account → Google` and login with your Google account credentials.

After logging in successfully, you should be able to configure mail and contact sync.

[image]

[image]

[image]